# supermarket dataclasses

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Union

@dataclass
class OtherStock:
    name:str  = "gold"
    units:int = 7
    price_per_unit : float = 150000


@dataclass
class FoodStock:
    name:str = "bread"
    units:int = 2
    price_per_unit: float = 700
    expiration_date: str = "2021-02-16"


stock = Union[OtherStock,FoodStock]

def is_expired(inventory:stock,date:str)->bool:
    if type(inventory) == OtherStock:
        return False
    if date == inventory.expiration_date:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(is_expired("bread","2021-02-16"))
print(is_expired("gold","2021-02-16"))
```

The code should compare both attributes in `date` and `expiration_date` and should return `True` if the product is expired. `OtherStock` can't expire so it returns `false` every time. If I try to run it I get an `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'expiration_date'`.

Comment: `type` returns a string. You want to use `isinstance` instead.

Comment: ok but the mistake is in if date == inventory.expiration_date

Comment: Declaring `is_expired()`'s first argument `inventory:stock` won't cause whatever is passed to be converted to one of those types — you actually have to pass an instance of one of them.

Comment: What will you do when you have 2 batches of bread with different expiration dates?

Answer (score 1):

Your code passes strings to `is_expired`, not objects. `"bread"` is a string.

Maybe you want `print(is_expired(FoodStock(), "2021-02-16"))`?

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, the problem is with `inventory.expiration_date`, and like the error says, `inventory` is a `str`. And the first arguments you pass ("bread" and "gold") are indeed strings.

You'll need to create your stock objects first. Python won't do it for you. However, [according to documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), Python automatically creates initialisers for us. That's the `FoodStock(...)` and `OtherStock(...)` calls you see below.

```
today = "2021-02-16"
print(is_expired(FoodStock(name="bread", expiration_date="2021-02-12"), today))
print(is_expired(OtherStock(name="gold"), today))
```

Here, we used keyword arguments to specify individual fields.

You may also want to consider checking `date >= inventory.expiration_date` instead of `==`.